# HTML PHP form file upload - display file name on submit and send file to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, file-upload

I have an html form I have a file upload button - it works the file is uploaded to an upload folder. I need to

- have the uploaded file name display on submit. It should be added to this block:

  ```
  <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
    <div id="sadhu">
      <p class="general_site">First Name:<strong><?php echo $firstname;?></strong></p>
      <p class="general_site">Last Name:<strong><?php echo $lastname;?></strong></p>
      <p class="general_site">Email:<strong><?php echo $email;?></strong></p>
      <p class="general_site">Theme:<strong><?php echo $theme;?></strong></p>
      <p class="general_site">Type:<strong><?php echo $type;?></strong></p>
      <p class="general_site">Upload:<strong><?php print_r($_FILES['datafile']);?></strong></p>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  ```

At the moment print_r shows the file but in a messy array I need to clean it up...

- Once this form is submitted the email that comes though does not have the attached file. In the part that sends the email all I have is this:

  ```
  //If there is no error, send the email
  if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "First Name: $firstname \n\nLast Name: $lastname \n\nEmail: $email \n\nTheme: $theme \n\nType of Abstract: $type \n\nUpload: $datafile \n\n";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first question use `$_FILES['datafile']['name']`

for the second one, attaching files to an email is a bit more tricky. have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/), it helped me a lot when i was starting out

Comment: Hiya Bru :) Excellent - well I must say I figured the $FILES bit out - so thank you, will checkout that tutorial.